How to calculate amount to add to an invoice to include credit card fee and tax on credit card fee
An invoice has a total of 10,000.
I need to add a 2% cc fee to the amount, but also charge 5% tax on the cc fee.

So, 0.02 * 10000 = $200  and the Total becomes 10,200.
Adding 0.05 * 200 = 10, the total becomes 10,210
Which, of course raises the CC Charge, which then raises the tax charge.

How can I calculate the correct amount to add to my invoice total, so when paid the balance will be zero?
Thanks everyone for the quick responses.
The spec has now changed, in that the CC Fee doesn't apply to the tax amount, therefore, no more circular reference.  So, I no longer need an answer, but won't delete the post as there are some good responses here.

Generally, follow the contract. What does the contract say? In any case, accounting questions are off topic.

The credit card fee is not income to you. It is income to the credit card company, that you are paying. I would be surprised if you have to pay tax on it.

Thanks for the responses, but I don't have a choice in this. It is a requirement for a client and comes from their lawyers.

If it's a requirement for the client then they need to tell you how to calculate it.

@keshlam The cost of the goods is not income to you, it is income to the vendors, that you are paying. And yet it is still taxable. Certainly it's possible that CC fees are not taxable in OP's jurisdiction, but I wouldn't assume that is the case.

@Acccumulation: Different tax systems, different rules. One of the differences between wholesale and retail in the US is who is responsible for collecting tax. I would be surprised if anybody has to pay credit card fee taxes except the credit card company, but nobody ever said that government policies had to make sense.

If you want the total invoice amount to be 10,000 after you deduct a 2% fee with a 5% tax on the fee, which makes the net total fee 2% * 1.05 = 2.1%, you are solving for the equation
x - (x * 0.021) = 10,000
x (1 - 0.021) = 10,000
x = 10,000 / (1 - 0.021)
x = 10,214.50


so when paid the balance will be zero?

If a customer has a bill for 10,000 and they pay 10,000, their balance is zero.
You don't state where you're from but in the US, the customer is not responsible for taxes and CC fees, the seller is.  You can choose to pass on CC fees and taxes, but it is not required. The "tax" that's reported on a receipt is just indicating that the seller is passing on some tax to the buyer. Ate the end of the day the seller is taxed on their net total taxable sales (I am not sure if CC fees are taxed or not), not per-invoice, so there could be some rounding difference. CC fees are generally not accounted for separately, although sellers can either just bake it into their prices, pass through an extra fee for using credit cards, or give a "cash discount".  It depends on how much the seller wants to be perceived as "padding the bill".

This calculation is known as grossing up. In this example, x is the gross and 10,000 is the net.

The problematic part of the question begins at " which, of course raises the CC Charge, which then raises the tax charge".
The "2% cc fee" is a nominal rate of fee supposed to cover your costs in using a credit processing service to collect your payment.  Applying that rate to a base charge of $10,000, you've calculated a credit card fee of $200.  I would be hugely surprised if your actual costs of processing the payment by credit card came anywhere close to $200, so you're almost certainly getting some extra income by applying a $200 fee.  There's absolutely no need to charge extra because $200 already covers your costs.  You haven't specified your location so we don't know which laws apply in your jurisdiction - but it's possible that it's even illegal in your jurisdiction to apply a credit card processing fee that's not related to your actual credit card processing costs.
The other aspect that's potentially a breach of your laws (in whatever jurisdiction you may be) is that you appear to want to calculate a tax on a tax.  You haven't specified the nature of the "5% tax" but it appears likely that the tax should apply in respect of the supply of goods or services (or some related description).  Calculating the tax component on the credit card fee is probably correct, but that will of course depend on the precise wording of the relevant tax law.  Calculating a tax on the $10 tax component is very likely illegal, again depending on the precise wording of the relevant tax law.
Unless you have evidence that a $200 credit card fee is insufficient to cover your actual credit card processing costs, your final answer is $10,210.  Don't go chasing your tail any further after that point.
Disclaimer: I'm neither an accountant or a tax lawyer, and we don't even know which laws apply in your jurisdiction.

I'm editing (adding to) this answer in response to comments below.
There was a news item on ABC News (Australia) tonight - credit card fees are a topic of concern at present and the government may launch a formal inquiry into them.  The TV news reported that the average transaction processing fee for businesses on a $100 Mastercard/Visa credit card purchase was 90 cents (would be cheaper for either debit card or EFTPOS).  This is based on Australian payment systems, but it's probably not very different in AVG's jurisdiction, wherever that may be.
If the credit card fee scaled smoothly with size of transaction, then the credit card transaction fee on a $10,000 invoice would be $90.  But that's not true of actual costs, of course.  The real costs of credit card transaction processing lie in the cost of good security software, and buying access to secure networks, and human sys admins to keep it all running.  The number of electrons or photons that need to be pushed around doesn't really vary significantly between a $1 transaction and a $1,000,000 transaction.
If AVG is involved in a business issuing invoices of $10,000 at a time, there's an excellent chance that the business can negotiate a favourable rate with their credit processing facility.  2% already seems like a high rate to me - I'm not sure why one of the commenters thinks that the rate might be "quite a bit more than 2%".

Greg, Thanks for the response, but this is a requirement for a client. I don't have any choice. I need to figure out how to do it.

Unless your client thinks that somehow laws don't apply to them, the same considerations apply whether it's your invoice or your client's.  You won't be doing any favours for your client if you increase the amount of the invoice by 0.05% but this increase puts them in breach of the law.

"Applying that rate to a base charge of $10,000, you've calculated a credit card fee of $200. I would be hugely surprised if your actual costs of processing the payment by credit card came anywhere close to $200" Huh? The interchange is quite often quite a bit more than 2%. Do you think when OP says "CC fee", they mean "fee for the time I spent processing the credit card transaction"?

In what jurisdiction is it illegal to charge a credit card processing fee that doesn't exactly match the amount paid by the merchant?

@stannius Australia, for one example.  https://www.accc.gov.au/system/files/1193_Payment%20surcharges_FA_web03.pdf

I am going to assume that your explanation is correct and legal for your jurisdiction.

An invoice has a total of 10,000.
I need to add a 2% cc fee to the amount, but also charge 5% tax on the
cc fee.

So, 0.02 * 10000 = $200  and the Total becomes 10,200.
Adding 0.05 * 200 = 10, the total becomes 10,210
Which, of course raises the CC Charge, which then raises the tax charge.

How can I calculate the correct amount to add to my invoice total, so
when paid the balance will be zero?

This isn't an unusual situation. Many charities essentially do this. If you decide to donate $100 to them they ask do you want to reimburse them for the credit card fee. So either you spend $100 and they get a little less, or you pay more than $100 and they get exactly $100.
You are simply calculating how much to tell the credit card company to charge so that when they take their fee and you send the money that you owe the tax authority you end up with $10,00 as you wanted.
This is a loop that you can quickly program to calculate the taxes and the fees on each amount until the desired amount is the result. With the rates involved the numbers will be very close after the first loop. When I used Excel to calculate the fees and taxes I was off by ~$4.41  initially and then off by ~$0.09 after the first approximation.
You could also try and use algebra to back calculate it, but using the what if function in excel will quickly loop through the possibilities.

Using what if for linear functions is overkill. It's simple algebra.
